# Polylang automatic sync for posts

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I'm working on a multilingual wordpress website using the Polylang plug-in on pages and custom post types.

What I'm looking for is a way to have every post synch automatically, without user input. When creating a new post type, a translation would be automatically created and all contents copied.

[image]

So the user wouldn't see this panel at all, or at least *not* have the chance to edit the translation or (especially) turn the sync off. I guess this could be done by changing user roles privileges but the post would definitely have to automatically sync.

I checked [this article](https://polylang.pro/doc/filter-reference/) but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Needed something similar, dug up this undocumented function:

```php
global $polylang;
// third parameter sets synchronisation
$polylang->sync_post_model->copy_post($post_id, $lang, true);
```

This duplicates the content to the chosen language and enables synchronisation.

Example using 'save_post:

```php
function auto_translate($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (!$update) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent recursion when publishing translations
    remove_action('save_post', 'auto_translate', 999, 3);

    global $polylang;
    $langs = ['nb', 'se', 'dk'];
    $current_translations = pll_get_post_translations($post_id);

    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        if (!isset($current_translations[$lang])) {
            $polylang->sync_post_model->copy_post($post_id, $lang, true);
        }
    }
}

// needs low priority or the synchronisation option wont be saved
add_action('save_post', 'auto_translate', 999, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by steinoy is good but generates an additional unwanted draft post. Here's an improved solution:

```
function auto_translate($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (!$update) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent creation of additional duplicate draft posts
    if ( $post->post_status == 'draft' ){
        return;
    }

    // prevent recursion when publishing translations
    remove_action('save_post', 'auto_translate', 999, 3);

    global $polylang;
    $langs = ['nb', 'se', 'dk'];
    $current_translations = pll_get_post_translations($post_id);
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    
    if ($post_type == 'post') {
        foreach ($langs as $lang) {
            if (!isset($current_translations[$lang])) {
                $polylang->sync_post_model->copy_post($post_id, $lang, true);
            }
        }
    }
}

// needs low priority or the synchronisation option wont be saved
add_action('save_post', 'auto_translate', 999, 3);
```